# User Stored Proc Returns NULL--underlying query works as planned

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Yes, it's another one of these. Questions with near-identical titles did not apply or I didn't see the connection.

My usp looks like this:

```
>    CREATE PROCEDURE uspHasItem
>         @sr_id INT,
>         @ActionableItem VARCHAR(1) OUTPUT
>    AS BEGIN
>         SELECT @ActionableItem = (CASE
>         WHEN EXISTS (
>                      SELECT stuff FROM here
>                       WHERE condition
>                         AND field = (
>                                      SELECT MAX(something)
>                                        FROM another_place
>                                       WHERE field1 = @sr_id)
>                     )
>         THEN '1'
>         ELSE '0' END);
>     END
>     RETURN
```

I call this in the customary fashion, AFAIK:

```
DECLARE @Actionable VARCHAR(1);
EXEC uspHasItem
    @sr_id = 1222,
    @ActionableItem = @Actionable;
SELECT @Actionable AS AI;
```

I can verify the input values to be valid and it doesn't matter what I provide, and in anycase it shouldn't matter what the input value is--I always get NULL as my output.

Now, if I pull out that query and tweak it provide the @sr_id values from a table:

```
SELECT
 SRT.SR_ID,
 CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (
                     SELECT stuff FROM here
                      WHERE condition
                        AND field = (
                                     SELECT MAX(something)
                                       FROM another_place
                                      WHERE field1 = SRT.SR_ID)
                    )
        THEN '1'
        ELSE '0' END AS ACTIONABLE
FROM SRTABLE SRT;
```

I get exactly the result I expect. I am not seeing the problem and am not getting any error.

How is it possible to not get *any* value, and is my test execution of the usp with the SELECT statement afterward where the actual problem is? Suggestions?

Comment: Try taking the ; off each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you forget `output`?

```
DECLARE @Actionable VARCHAR(1)

EXEC uspHasItem
    @sr_id = 1222,
    @ActionableItem = @Actionable output
SELECT @Actionable AS AI
```

Answer (score -1):

When you run your proc, don't put a ; after every line, this breaks the scope, also add OUTPUT

```
DECLARE @Actionable VARCHAR(1)
EXEC uspHasItem
    @sr_id = 1222,
    @ActionableItem = @Actionable OUTPUT
SELECT @Actionable AS AI;
```

Comment: Semi colons don't affect scope. Terminating statements without a semi colon is deprecated.

Comment: You guys nailed it in about 4 ms. Yup Solved. I go stick my head in the toilet and flush now.

Comment: Martin, you're right on the scope, sorry to provide mis-info... old habits.